# Dev certificate on aspnetcore docker container

Tags: docker, ssl, aspnetcore-environment

I'm new to Docker and I have run into a trouble running my app in docker due missing ssl certificates. How do I run aspnetcore application in docker with non-development environment using dev certificates?

I have the following `Dockerfile` generated by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
COPY [...other libraries...]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

When I run it from the Visual Studio with the default setup (development), it connects Docker and everything runs fine. However, I want to use a different appsettings file (`appsettings.docker.json`) because I need some different values when running in Docker and I'm already using my `appsettings.development.json` for my standard run from the VS. Thus I set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker`. This is causing a pain as I'm suddenly getting an `InvalidOperationException`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126628/2800222) answer, I have figured out that dotnet generates the dev certs automagically when the environment variable is `Development`. How can that be fixed for a differently called environment?

I did try to use the `dotnet dev-certs https` command in the Dockerfile, however, build failed saying that there is no sdk in the image and thus doesn't know the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dotnet dev-certs with aspnet docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282468/using-dotnet-dev-certs-with-aspnet-docker-image)

Comment: I did try that but root folder is empty in the final image, not sure whether the cert hasn't been created at all or it is another issue.

Comment: You need to run `dotnet dev-certs` in the build stage of your Dockerfile for there to be something to copy. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will look deeper into it.

Comment: @HansKilian It seems there is no `.dotnet` folder in the root, there is an `.aspnet` folder that contains pfx certs for my app in https/myApp.pfx, but the runtime doesn't seem to find it there.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding these 2 lines

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
# Add the line below ---------------------------------------------------
RUN dotnet dev-certs https
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
COPY [...other libraries...]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
# Add the line below ---------------------------------------------------
COPY --from=publish /root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/* /root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Comment: I did try that, unfortunately still the same error.

Comment: It generates a certificate and puts it to the right place. The application is started, but a warning is shown:
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[8]
      The ASP.NET Core developer certificate is not trusted. For information about trusting the ASP.NET Core developer certificate, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/https-trust-dev-cert.
A browser also warns on untrusted certificate